# fuerte source install - gen_rosinstall.py not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install fuerte from source but it seems like http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py is not found any longer. Is this a temporary issue and to be resolved soon or is installation of fuerte (and older versions) from source using the online rosinstall generation script not supported any longer?
If it's the latter, is there any other source that provides a rosinstall file for the different install variants (desktop, desktop-full, etc.)?

Thanks,
Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82421/fuerte-source-install---gen_rosinstall.py-not-found/) by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on ROS Answers with karma: 360 on 2013-09-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michael Beardsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/6811/michael-beardsworth/) on 2013-10-06**:
Thomas,
Have you had any success with this?  I'm running into the same issue.  It looks like rosinstall_generator (which seems to be intended to replace this functionality) doesn't support fuerte.

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on 2013-10-06**:
I haven't come across a solution / workaround yet. All documentation related to fuerte source install and gen_rosinstall.py seems to state that pre-groovy the gen_rosinstall.py is to be used, but it seems like the gen_rosinstall.py script disappeared without providing an alternative.

**Comment by [Michael Beardsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/6811/michael-beardsworth/) on 2013-10-06**:
It looks like the source for the gen_rosinstall.py tool is here:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/browser/stacks/ros_release/branches/fuerte/job_generation/website/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rev=16603

I'll start hunting for the database it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I pulled out the source for gen_rosinstall.py and hacked together a quick solution at https://github.com/mbeards/gen_rosinstall .  It might be worthwhile to either set up a legacy packages.ros.org or update the newer tools to support Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Michael Beardsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/6811/michael-beardsworth/) with karma: 46 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on 2013-10-06**:
Awesome, thanks for putting together the script. I do agree that updating the tools to support previous distributions would be good as there's still a wide range of users relying on fuerte for their projects who might need source install.

**Comment by [witwicki](https://answers.ros.org/users/8771/witwicki/) on 2013-11-13**:
Hi, how do I go about using this script?  I have downloaded it locally, and run it locally with python, but I'm not sure how to format my rosinstall command.

Something like:
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

(By the way, I am trying to install fuerte from source, following the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source.)

**Comment by [pr2_fan123](https://answers.ros.org/users/5674/pr2_fan123/) on 2013-11-15**:
I would like to know aswell how to use that gen_rosinstall.py to install ros fuerte from source.

**Comment by [witwicki](https://answers.ros.org/users/8771/witwicki/) on 2013-11-18**:
I got it to work by piping the output of the python command to a local file, and afterwards passing the name of that local file to rosinstall. (I.e., replace "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no" with the name of the local file).

**Comment by [pr2_fan123](https://answers.ros.org/users/5674/pr2_fan123/) on 2013-11-18**:
Hm, i think i already tried this and it didn't work. Could you give an example of the full rosinstall command when the gen_rosinstall.py file lies in my home/user directory? I also want the fuerte desktop-full variant so i'm not sure how to pass those params.

**Comment by [witwicki](https://answers.ros.org/users/8771/witwicki/) on 2013-11-18**:
In a bash shell, try running this line:  python generate_rosinstall.py --rosdistro=fuerte --overlay=no --variant=desktop-full > temp && rosinstall ~/ros temp